# ng-options default option that displays all options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a ng-options pick list that I want there to be a default option that displays all options; When you click an item in the list it should filter when you click on the default value it should show all values.  I could have sworn in the past I was able to do this using an option html element with a value set to "", but this is not working, can someone help me work this out.  Fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/nzfks0rq/

```
<select ng-model="todoFilter" ng-options="todo.name as todo.name for todo in todos" class='form-control'>
   <option value="">Choose Vendor</option>
</select>
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:{name: todoFilter}">
     {{todo.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The @mrust is right, but in your case you can just use simple `search` logic as that example provide

```
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
```

this code more important to understand how organize search by one or multiple fields using default filter

```
<label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
<label>Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"></label><br>
<label>Equality <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"></label><br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Best regards

Egor

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your default options value is interpreted as `null`
So in my opinion the easies way to solve your issue is just add watch to your filter and convert it to empty string when it's not defined.

```
$scope.$watch('todoFilter', function(val){
  $scope.todoFilter = $scope.todoFilter? $scope.todoFilter : "";
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzfks0rq/4/)